# PHP: how to resolve a dynamic property of an object that is multiple levels deep

Tags: php, mysql, string, object, amazon-web-services

I am have written a helper function to "cleanup" callback variables for input into MySQL. This is the function that I wrote:

```php
public function string($object, $objectPath) {
    if (!empty($object->$objectPath) || $object->$objectPath !== '') {
        $value = $object->$objectPath;
    } else {
        return 'NULL';
    }
    if (!empty($value) || $value != '') {
        return "'".str_replace("'","''",$value)."'";
    } else {
        return 'NULL';
    }
}
```

Now, `$object` is always an object returned by the call, and `$objectPath` is always a string to points to a given value. Here's where the problem comes in. This works:

```
$value = $this->db->string($object, 'foo');
```

However, this does not work:

```
$value = $this->db->string($object, 'foo->bar->foo1->bar1');
```

Whenever `$objectPath` is more than "one layer" deep, I get the following error from (Amazon's) client library:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_Order::getFoo->Bar() in /path/to/Model.php on line 63
```

The code block that the error refers to is this:

```php
public function __get($propertyName)
    {
       $getter = "get$propertyName"; 
       return $this->$getter(); // this is line 63
    }
```

`$object` is not XML, so I can't use `SimpleXMLElement` and `XPath`.

What is the problem with my code? Is it that am I concatenating an object and a string? If so, how can I make that possible? How can I get this function to do what I intended it to do?

By the way, I'm using PHP 5.4.27.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't automatically resolve a string containing multiple path levels to children of an object like you are attempting to do.

This will **not** work even if `$obj` contains the child hierarchy you are expecting:

```
$obj = ...;  
$path = 'level1->level2->level3';
echo $obj->$path;    // WRONG!
```

You would need to split up the path and "walk" through the object trying to resolve the final property.
Here is an example based on yours:

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->name = 'Fred';
$obj->job = new stdClass();
$obj->job->position = 'Janitor';
$obj->job->years = 4;
print_r($obj);

echo 'Years in current job: '.string($obj, 'job->years').PHP_EOL;


function string($obj, $path_str)
{
    $val = null;

    $path = preg_split('/->/', $path_str);
    $node = $obj;
    while (($prop = array_shift($path)) !== null) {
        if (!is_object($obj) || !property_exists($node, $prop)) {
            $val = null;
            break;

        }
        $val = $node->$prop;
        // TODO: Insert any logic here for cleaning up $val

        $node = $node->$prop;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Here it is working: http://3v4l.org/9L4gc

Comment: Hi, sorry it's not working for you. As you can see from the link I provided it works on a standard object. You might try experimenting with changing `!property_exists($node, $prop)` to `isset($node->$prop)`

Answer (score 0):

With @itsmejodie's help, I finally got a working solution:

```php
public function string($node, $objectPath) {
    $value = NULL;
    $path = explode('->', $objectPath);
    while (($prop = array_shift($path)) !== NULL) {
        if (!$node->$prop) {
            break;
        }
        $value = $node->$prop;
        $node = $node->$prop;
    }
    if (is_string($value)) {
        return "'".str_replace("'","''",$value)."'";
    } else {
        return 'NULL';
    }
}
```

The key for me was to see that, as @itsmejodie put it, "PHP doesn't automatically resolve a string containing multiple path levels to children of an object." In a string like, `'foo->bar->foo1->bar2'`, PHP won't convert the `->`'s into the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`, thus appending a string to an object, e.g., `$object->foo->bar->foo1->bar2`, just won't work.